# Kivy - Bad visual quality when using screen manager

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I want to use the screen manager inside a BoxLayout but my labels and buttons don't come out sharp when I do it this way. Anyone else have this problem?

[image]

Here is the .kv file I used:

```
<Root>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        id: main
        BoxLayout:
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Placeholder'
        BoxLayout:
            id: menu_choice
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    Label:
                        text: 'Placeholder'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (1, 0.05)
        Label:
            id: status_message
            text: 'Test message'
            font_size: sp(11)
```

Where Root inherits from BoxLayout. I'm on OS X using kivy 1.8.0 and python 2.7.8

I'm actually getting the same quality when using a TabbedPanel:

[image]

I have a second monitor connected to my MacBook. And on the page for installation instructions on Kivy.org it does say that "there can be a limitation on some OS X with more than one monitor. The application will crash when you try to start it on the second monitor." But I get the same output when I disconnect the monitor and Kivy never actually crashes.

Comment: This is interesting, I might normally expect it to occur if the screen isn't lined up with the pixels of the display but I don't see why that would be the case here.

Comment: I thought it'd be something with my Kivy installation since it occurs using the TabbedPanel view as well. But reinstalling Kivy did not solve anything.

Comment: Could you post your python file as well, so that the example is easy to directly test?

Comment: I put the python and kivy code, along with the terminal output in a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/feynman21/e9f6c1c870e7ab9afda3). The hash lib error is also something I need to fix, but I don't suppose that would have anything to do with the way Kivy widgets display text